# Using downgradeModule to create an Angular hybrid app

Tags: angularjs, angular, migration

I want to upgrade my Angular JS application to use Angular (2+), and for this I want to use the `downgradedModule`:

app.module.js (Angular JS module)

```
import angular from 'angular';
import { environment } from '../environment'

import { downgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

const bootstrapFn = (extraProviders) => {
  const platformRef = platformBrowserDynamic(extraProviders);
  return platformRef.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
};

const downgradedModule = downgradeModule(bootstrapFn);

(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app', [
      /* my other Angular JS modules */
      downgradedModule
    ])
..........
```

app.module.ts (Angular module)

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { UpgradeModule, setAngularLib } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import angular from 'angular';
import { MyComponent} from './example-components/my-component.component';

setAngularLib(angular);

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    UpgradeModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    MyComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    MyComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private upgrade: UpgradeModule) { }

  ngDoBootstrap() {}
}
```

When I run `npm start`, it says that `angular is not defined` and points to the `angular.module('app',...` line from the app.module.js file. If I go to the only page which contains Angular JS and also Angular components, I don't get any error, but the page is not displaying anything.

If I try to use `UpgradeModule` into the app.module.ts file like this:

```
ngDoBootstrap() {
    this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.documentElement, ['app'], {
      strictDi: false
    });
  }
```

The application is working but I get an error into the browser's console:
`Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress`. I understand that this can be avoided if I use `downgradedModule` which doesn't work for now as I explained.

Do I have to do something else to bootstrap the application, or what is the problem? Thanks!